# jQuery append not displaying html with each method

Tags: jquery, append, each

I have a list of elements.

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
  $(function() {
    var liNodes = $("li");
    liNodes.each(function(index, value) {
      var span = $("<span></span>");
      value.append(span);
      console.log(value);
    });
  });
```

I want to iterate over the li elements, appending a span class to each but instead it displays this:

- One[object Object]
- Two[object Object]
- Three[object Object]

What am I doing wrong here? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `value` is an Element object, not a jQuery object, so you're calling the native `append()` method, not the jQuery one. To fix this either convert `value` to a jQuery object first:

```js
$(function() {
  var liNodes = $("li");
  liNodes.each(function(index, value) {
    var span = $("<span>Foo</span>");
    $(value).append(span);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Or create the `span` Element object and use `appendChild()` on `value`:

```js
$(function() {
  var liNodes = $("li");
  liNodes.each(function(index, value) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = 'Foo';
    value.appendChild(span);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

With all that said, note that if you want to create an identical element in all `li`, then you don't need a loop at all, it's a one-liner:

```
$('li').append('<span>Foo</span>');
```

Comment: thank you! you gave me multiple useful insights here.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
    var liNodes = $("li");
    liNodes.each(function(index, value) {
      //var span = $("<span></span>");
      let span = document.createElement("span");
      value.append(span);
      console.log(value);
    });
  });
```

You can play around [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3g471cvx/)

Answer (score 0):

Just one line of change in your code everything else works fine.

```js
  var liNodes = $("li");
    liNodes.each(function(index, value) {
        var span = "<span>Foo</span>";
        $(value).append(span);
        console.log(value);
    });
```